# jQuery click to change CSS

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a simple question but don't know exactly how to achieve this. All I know is that I have to use the `click()` function.

Basically, I have a div with the id `#box1`. I applied the CSS style `overflow:auto` so that there will be a vertical scroll-bar if the table length (a long table is inside #box1) exceeds the width of the div `#box1`.

Now I wanted to add a link below the div. The link should do the following:

- On-click, add the CSS for div `#box1` from `overflow:auto` to `overflow:visible`
- Simultaniously, while it changes the CSS above, the link should change to display a new link (the old one disappears) that will change CSS back to `overflow:auto` when clicked.

Comment: I suggest you post an example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `css` method.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#box1').css('overflow', function(i, o) {
        return o == 'auto' ? 'visible' : 'auto';
    })
});
```

And instead of hiding/showing 2 different buttons, you can use `text` method:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(event) {
    // ...  
    $(this).text(function(i, text){
       return text == 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show';
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6Nc8/

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wbjSX/**

```
$('#theLink').click(function() {
    if (turnToVisible) {
        $('#box1').css('overflow', 'visible');
        turnToVisible = false;
        $('#theLink').text('foobar');
    }
    else {
        $('#box1').css('overflow', 'auto');
        turnToVisible = true;
        $('#theLink').text('foobarbaz');
    }
});
```

Something like that should get you started.

It basically stores what you want the div to be like in a variable `turnToVisible`. You can use the `text` function to change the text of the link, and the `css` function to change CSS.

Comment: You've fallen into the unintentional global variable antipattern, you should explicitly declare the `turnToVisible` variable.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Works exactly how I wanted. But what does the comment above me mean? Is something wrong with the code?

Comment: @bmorris591 See fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you need to switch on the text:

```
<a id="myDivLink" href="javascript:void(0);">Disable scrolling</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDivLink").click(function(){
    var anchor = $(this);
    if(anchor.html()==="Disable scrolling") {
      $("#myDiv").css("overflow","visible");
      anchor.html("Enable scrolling");
    } else {
      $("#myDiv").css("overflow","auto");
      anchor.html("Disable scrolling");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

How's that?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="#box1"></div>
<a href="#" id="#toggle">Toggle</a>
```

JS:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#toggle").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($("#box1").css("overflow") === "auto"){
                $("#box1").css("overflow", "visible");
            }else{
                $("#box1").css("overflow", "auto");
            }
        });
    });
}(window.jQuery));
```

Basically, you'll need to stop the link from loading another page with `e.preventDefault()`. Then, if the box has `overflow: auto`, set it to `overflow: visible` and vice versa.